# Upload Photos to Google Photos using a For-Loop

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-photos

I am using Google Photos API to upload more than 2 million images into my Google Account. The goal is to write a for-loop to go over all images in a directory and upload them to google photos. The for-loop works fine for a period of time but eventually stops working. Here is the code:

```py
    i=0
    k=0
    tokens = []
    upload_url = 'https://photoslibrary.googleapis.com/v1/uploads'
    service = Service(API_SERVICE_NAME, VERSION, SCOPES, SECRET_ID=cred)

    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".JPG" ) or file.endswith(".jpg" ):            
            i = i + 1               
            token = pickle.load(open('token_photoslibrary_v1.pickle', 'rb'))                    
            image_path = os.path.join(image_dir, file)
            # response = upload_images(image_path, file, token)
            headers = {
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token.token,
                'Content-type': 'application/octet-stream',
                'X-Goog-Upload-Protocol': 'raw',
                'X-Goog-File-Name': file,
                'X-Goog-Upload-File-Name': view+file
            }
            img = open(image_path, 'rb').read()
            response = requests.post(upload_url, data=img, headers=headers)    
            tokens.append(response.content.decode('utf-8'))  
            
        if i%50==0 and i>0: #call every 50
            k = k + 1  
            print(f'{k} batch is uploading')
            new_media_items = [{'simpleMediaItem': {'uploadToken': tok}} for tok in tokens]
            request_body = {
                'newMediaItems': new_media_items
            }
            upload_response = service.mediaItems().batchCreate(body=request_body).execute()    
            tokens = []
```

and the error is:

```
<HttpError 400 when requesting https://photoslibrary.googleapis.com/v1/mediaItems:batchCreate?alt=json returned "Request must contain a valid upload token.". Details: "Request must contain a valid upload token.">
```

My account has Google One activated and I have 2T space.

Comment: Does it run for about an hour (3600 seconds)? If so, I suspect the token's expiring. You'll need to ensure the token is refreshed before it expires. If there's a Google SDK for Photos, it will take care of refreshing for you.

Comment: I may be incorrect. There may not be an API Client for photoslibrary. Curious.

Comment: It is around an hour. But the token does not expire. It just wouldn't run anymore. I modified it to recursively go back to the function and run the function again if the error occurs but it will throw the same error again and again. The only solution is to turn off the kernel and run the script again and it will work just fine again (until it hits the error).
I wonder if Google has some sort of limitation on it

Comment: Yes, there's undoubtedly quota too. You can check the Merritt and quota usage for a Project's API from the Console: `https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/photoslibrary.googleapis.com/quotas?project=${PROJECT}`

Comment: If quota is the problem why when I shut down the kernel and turn it back on it starts working? the quota is limited per day not per run, right?

Comment: I don't know how the quota is set for photoslibrary. I was just showing you how to check it.

Comment: Thanks. I still have this issue.

Comment: Finally I found the problem. After several calls token expires so we need to recreate it. So I added a try and except statement so that if the program throws error it creates the token again and run the function recursively.

Answer (score 0):

Quick search shows a token is valid for [one day](https://developers.google.com/photos/library/guides/upload-media#:%7E:text=An%20upload%20token%20is%20valid%20for%20one%20day)

This is vague (like Google PHP API docs) but [this documentation](https://developers.google.com/photos/library/guides/upload-media) is what I use.
Being vague, I expect other Stackover users will mark my answer down (and your question). Sadly this is what Stackoverflow has become.

I am writing similar code requirement, and will initially parse a directory list as a flat array containing all subdirectories, then dive into each. I keep a file limit to throttle uploads (ideally a byte count limit instead of a file count would be good) as we are talking a large amount of data especially if these are hi res images, or videos.

This throttling allows a balance and I use a cron job to periodically process my file volume. If a local directory is empty PHP code will delete it.